# Here sdk navigation in shortest mode prefer loops over U-Turns

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using HERE-sdk to navigate through several waypoint. When the route is computed, there is sometimes a u-turn when arriving to a waypoint in order to get to the next one as shown in the snapshot bellow between waypoints 1 and 2:

[image]

But during navigation, when I reach waypoint 1, a dynamic route recalculation occurs and make me do a loop to reach waypoint 2 (instead of making me do a u-turn) as shown in the snapshot bellow (In red: the undesired recalculation loop; In green: the expected maneuvers)

[image: In red: the undesired recalculation loop; In green: the expected maneuvers]

I tried both SHORTEST and FASTEST routing mode but, even if the green route is far shortest, it is not chosen by the navigation engine.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide example coordinates of a route and code sample for creating a route that you are using ?

Comment: The code is a simple RoutePlan created using successive calls to addWaypoint(RouteWaypoint). The RoutePlan is then calculated using CoreRouter.calculateRoute(RoutePlan, Listener) and the resulting MapRoute is fed to NavigationManager. Coordinates of the example above : [1] 48.7748105,-3.3894145 [2] 48.7769159,-3.3900273 [3] 48.7730886,-3.3948699

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't been able to reproduce it. With provided coordinates, everything seems correct to me. 
Which version of SDK do you use ?
Is it happens during real driving or in simulation mode ?
With disabled dynamic rerouting, will it be the same or not ?
Is it happens always or periodically ?

Comment: please provide the route and a trace of the situation. It is quite hard for us to explain the situation without more information.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE premium SDK has changed over time with many improvements and updates. Please use the latest SDK for your use case as the problem is currently not reproducible.

We also provide several code examples for different use cases.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/routing.html

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples